# Unable to perform action for element which is visible through playwright -typescript

Tags: playwright

I am able to see the locator in UI and isvisible() condition is also satisfied through playwright script, but i am unable to perform click and fill actions on the same element.
Also script in playwright is passing while execution, but action is not performing in application's UI

Background: UI fields in the page are dynamically generated based on other functional operations
Attaching my html for reference,

[image]
[image]

Also tried to fetch the element with tag where I found 2 children nodes,

path - //ejs-dropdownlist//child::select[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smO2i.png) - displays(1 of 2 matching)

path -//ejs-dropdownlist//child::select[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6uRZ.png) - displays(0 matching)

Tried to reload the page and clearing of cache. None of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the visibility & clicking on element `ejs-dropdownlist/span` as this is the parent element , might be covering it. That should help.